# Рекомендации по безопасности при проектировании CMS?

Tags: apache, php, cms

Здравствуйте кодеры.

Начинаю проектировать очередную CMS, в очередной раз перечитал кучу мануалов, постеково изучил основные популярные открытые CMS, но хотелось бы знать, чего следует остерегаться при проектировании CMS? Какие рекомендации можете дать?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала наверное

1. шифруйте все данные, хранимые как в базе данных так и в кукисах (и логин и пароль и всё прочее)
2. особое внимание обращайте на обработку полей ввода (формат, длина и т.д.) Жёстко контролируйте ввод (возможно даже javascript)
3. неплохо бы предусмотреть https
4. уделите внимание отображению информации папок CMS (чтобы их содержимое браузер не показывал можно например воткнуть пустой index.html, ибо настройки серверов могут быть разными)
5. ну и в зависимости от средства разработки почаще смотрите информационные бюллютени безопасности

мож ещё кто-то что-нибудь добавит?